# Use BigQuery Python API to create view in one project referencing tables in another project

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to do the above, but I am getting the following error:

```
ERROR - exception: 404 POST https://bigquery.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/sandbox/datasets/my_dataset_long/tables?prettyPrint=false: Not found: Dataset prod:my_dataset_short
```

I am using end user credentials, and I have BQ access to both projects.

How do I create the View in `sandbox` project that queries `prod` project's datasets?

I followed the example [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/views#python) to the tee, except for my own query, which references the other project's table, and I still got the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to repeat the steps manually in BigQuery Console UI, by pasting the query into the editor and saving the View in my sandbox project.
I got the same error `Not found: Dataset ...`

Then I noticed the tooltip in the Save View dialog which said the **View must be in the same location as the referenced tables**.

Answer (score 1):

> View must be in the same location as the referenced tables.

The location mentioned here is a [region](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/views#view_limitations).

Most likely the issue here is with access rights. Try to [authorize your view with view access to dataset from another project](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/share-access-views#authorize_the_view_to_access_the_source_dataset):

> 1. Select the github_source_data dataset from Resources and click Share dataset.
> 2. In the Dataset permissions panel, click the Authorized views tab.
> 3. Under Share authorized view:
>
>    - For `Select project`, verify your project is selected.
>    - For `Select dataset`, choose shared_views.
>    - For `Select view`, type the view name: github_analyst_view.
>    - Click OK.
> 4. Click Add and then click Done.

In Python:

```
access_entries = source_dataset.access_entries
access_entries.append(
    bigquery.AccessEntry(None, "view", view.reference.to_api_repr())
)
source_dataset.access_entries = access_entries
source_dataset = client.update_dataset(
    source_dataset, ["access_entries"]
)  # API request
```